# Canon-TR4520 prints white on black since last update, wasting much ink

Tags: printing, canon

Printing from Brave, Firefox and `qpdfview` to **Canon-TR4520** only prints white on black wasting much ink.  The page is mostly black.  Sort of reverse-video.  Worked fine before recent updates.

I loaded a 'bad' pdf with LibreOffice writer and it printed okay from there, black on white.  Printing plain text files with lp works okay too.

Trying to figure out what's broken without wasting too many ink cartridges.  :-(

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.10
Release: 20.10
Codename: groovy      ... thanks for asking